# Can an n x m CSS Sprite be used to "repeat-x" to make the arrow's body longer?

Tags: css, css-sprites

For example, if there is a CSS sprite with n x m elements on it, and there is an arrow head, arrow body, and arrow tail, each separately.

Can the arrow head be attached to a `div` with variable length, with the background of the arrow body, but repeat-x or repeat-y, and attach the arrow tail?  I was thinking that you can't specify the region of the Sprite to repeat, so it will show other images on the sprite, won't it?  Or is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's nothing in the current CSS specifications that would allow for this, nor, as far as I know, anything in the upcoming CSS3 specifications.

There are no easy workarounds. You can try creating the repeating element in the sprite for as wide as you would need them, and hope that the png compression algorithm will compress the image down to a reasonable size, or simply use a separate image for this. You might also want to try using CSS gradients for this if you're working with repeating gradients.